# GROUP_BY WITH DISTINCT QUERY

Tags: oracle, group-by, distinct

Am using Oracle 12c, below is the column:

```
CENTER_ID     UNIT      EMPLOYEEID    LESSON  MINS_STUDIED  SECTION
I234          4         G01234         4.1        5            EX
I234          4         G01234         4.1        5            LN
I234          4         G01234         4.1        5            VO

I234          4         G0123          4.2        5            EX
I234          4         G0123          4.2        5            LN
I234          4         G0123          4.2        5            VO

I2345         5         G023           5.2       12            EX
I2345         5         G023           5.2       12            LN
I2345         5         G023           5.2       12            VO
```

From record 1 to 6, it contains 2 distinct employee_id who studied unit 4. In this case, I need total minutes spent per unit (center_id wise).

But I want to add only distinct MINS_STUDIED based on EMPLOYEE_ID.

So, total minutes spent for center_id I234 for unit 4 is (5+5)=10 and for center_id I2345 for unit 5 is 12.

I used the below query

```
    SELECT 
         COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ID),CENTER_ID,UNIT,
         SUM(DISTINCT MINS_STUDIED)
    FROM 
         TEST_DATA
    GROUP BY 
          CENTER_ID,DBD.UNIT;
```

The above query returns

```
center_id    UNIT  DISTINCT(EMPLOYEE_ID) TOTAL_MINS_STUDIED
I234          4      2                       5 
I2345         5      1                       12
```

**But, I need the output like below:**

```
center_id    UNIT  DISTINCT(EMPLOYEE_ID) TOTAL_MINS_STUDIED
I234          4      2                       10 
I2345         5      1                       12
```

Comment: What you wish to achieve is not fully clear to me - first of all, in your example there are 3 distinct `EMPLOYEEID` but in the desired output you wrote 2... and how do you calculate the sum 10?

Comment: Why is there duplicate data in your table in the first place?

Comment: Are you saying that the combination of CENTER_ID, UNIT, EMPLOYEEID and LESSON **should** determine the HOURS_STUDIED completely? If not, that is - if it is possible to have two rows with the same combination of the first four columns, but different HOURS_STUDIED, then your request makes no sense. If that is **not** possible, then you must `DISTINCT` the rows first, and only then apply aggregation.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the "mins studied" is the same value for all sections. Why not have the mins studied reflect the actual value for each section, or split the sections off into a different table. That would remove the unnecessary duplication and make your query easier.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume you only have two employeeID's and the last entry is a typo..

Simply get a distinct list before you calculate totals.

```
SELECT center_ID, unit, count(EmployeeID) cnt, sum(hours_Studied) sumHrs
FROM (SELECT distinct Center_ID, Unit, EmployeeID, hours_Studied 
      FROM test_data) TD
GROUP BY CENTER_ID, unit
```

Giving us: `I234, 4, 2, 10`

or using an analytic:  though I'm not sure how to handle what hours_studied to sum if they very by employeeID... so the ordering may be incorrect.

```
SELECT Center_ID, Unit, count(Distinct EmployeeID) cnt_Dist_Emp , sum(Hours_Studied) sum_hrs
FROM (Select row_number() over (PARTITION BY center_ID, unit, employeeID, Hours_Studied order by center_ID, unit, employeeID, Hours_Studied ) rn, TD.*
      FROM Test_data td)
WHERE RN = 1 
GROUP BY Center_ID, Unit
```