# Group by with distinct query

Tags: oracle, group-by, distinct

Am using Oracle 12c, below is the column:

```
CENTER_ID     UNIT      EMPLOYEEID    LESSON  MINS_STUDIED  SECTION
I234          4         G01234         4.1        5            EX
I234          4         G01234         4.1        5            LN
I234          4         G01234         4.1        5            VO

I234          4         G0123          4.2        5            EX
I234          4         G0123          4.2        5            LN
I234          4         G0123          4.2        5            VO

I2345         5         G023           5.2       12            EX
I2345         5         G023           5.2       12            LN
I2345         5         G023           5.2       12            VO
```

From record 1 to 6, it contains 2 distinct employee_id who studied unit 4. In this case, I need total minutes spent per unit (center_id wise).

But I want to add only distinct MINS_STUDIED based on EMPLOYEE_ID.

So, total minutes spent for center_id I234 for unit 4 is (5+5)=10 and for center_id I2345 for unit 5 is 12.

I used the below query

```
    SELECT 
         COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ID),CENTER_ID,UNIT,
         SUM(DISTINCT MINS_STUDIED)
    FROM 
         TEST_DATA
    GROUP BY 
          CENTER_ID,DBD.UNIT;
```

The above query returns

```
center_id    UNIT  DISTINCT(EMPLOYEE_ID) TOTAL_MINS_STUDIED
I234          4      2                       5 
I2345         5      1                       12
```

**But, I need the output like below:**

> ```
> center_id    UNIT  DISTINCT(EMPLOYEE_ID) TOTAL_MINS_STUDIED
> I234          4      2                       10 
> I2345         5      1                       12
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GROUP\_BY WITH DISTINCT QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47266337/group-by-with-distinct-query)

Answer (score 0):

The data appears to have repetition you need to ignore (caused by column "SECTION")

```
SELECT 
      CENTER_ID
    , UNIT
    , COUNT(DISTINCT EMPLOYEE_ID)
    , SUM(MINS_STUDIED)
FROM (
     select distinct CENTER_ID, UNIT, EMPLOYEEID , MINS_STUDIED 
     from TEST_DATA
     ) t
GROUP BY 
      CENTER_ID,UNIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with analytics functions, without subselects and group by:

---

Edit, added Employee_id to the partititon by clause of the SUM function

```
SELECT
    CENTER_ID, UNIT, 
    COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY CENTER_ID, UNIT) EMPLOYEES,
    SUM(MIN_STUDIED) OVER (PARTITION BY CENTER_ID, UNIT, EMPLOYEE_ID) TOTAL_MINS_STUDIED
FROM  
    TESTS_DATA
ORDER BY
    CENTER_ID, UNIT;
```